# Are there any tools to generate human-readable docs from Solidity source code?

Tags: solidity, documentation

Solidity's got built in support for generating JSON from docstrings, which does the hard part of extracting machine-readable data to build developer reference documentation. Are there any tools to take this and generate nicely formatted HTML from it?

Answer (score 2):

There's a tool called [Doxity](https://github.com/DigixGlobal/doxity) - made by the Digix folks - that will parse `.sol` files and create static HTML pages that can be served directly from Github.

Note that as of February 2017 the repository has been updated with a notice that Truffle integration is broken, so your mileage may vary.